# Cant find Modifiers

Tags: modifiers, versions

I am new to blender and I am using the newest version. Trying to follow the blender guru's tutorial for the donut scene. I found a hotkey online for subdivision surface because it wasn't available in the list of modifiers. But I haven't had such luck with finding a hotkey for solidify but it is also not including in my list of modifiers.

When I tried looking for subdivision surface, the object was a torus. Ctrl 1 worked for this so I was able to move on but it wasn't on the list of modifiers.

Now I am trying to add thickness to the icing on the donut, which is really half of a torus, solidify is not on the list of modifiers.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/index.html

Comment: The modifier list is based on the object type. You might want to [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/219468/edit) your question and add some more information about your scene. You can also add screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Select your object and click the spanner/wrench in the properties sidebar and then the Add Modifier dropdown:
[image]

The Solidifer and Subdivision Surface entries are arrowed below:
[image]

Comment: My modifier options do not have solidify or subdivision surface.

Answer (score 0):

As methaphor_set commented totally right:

The modifier list is based on the object type.

So e.g. a lattice does not have a subdivision surface modifier.

[image]

a light has no modifiers at all

[image]

so you should improve your question and tell us which object you have selected.

Comment: Yes indeed. If it hadn't been 1am here when I posted my answer I'd have remembered to add a sentence to that effect! :^)

Comment: You don't wanna know how often i had to delete my answer because i didn't look or read the "right" things.... :D